# Read subset of redshift table into glue session

Tags: pyspark, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

In my normal workflows I read an entire table into glue using the following:

```
orders = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options("redshift", connection_options = {
    "url": "",
    "dbtable": "orders",
    "user": "user",
    "password": "pw",
    "aws_iam_role": "iam_role",
    "redshiftTmpDir": args["TempDir"]
}).toDF()
```

If I wanted to only read a subset of this table in, is there a way to include a query in this function?  Something like the following:

```
orders = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options("redshift", connection_options = {
    "url": "",
    "dbtable": "select * from ts_dw.orders limit 1000",
    "user": "user",
    "password": "pw",
    "aws_iam_role": "iam_role",
    "redshiftTmpDir": args["TempDir"]
}).toDF()
```

I tried the above syntax of using a query in the dbtable and I get the following error: `Invalid operation: schema "select * from ts_dw" does not exist`

The basic point here is I want to avoid reading in the entire table.

Answer (score -1):

This means that the value you have given to `dbtable`, namely `select * from ts_dw.orders limit 1000` is invalid. You will need to use an actual table as a value, such as `dw.orders`.

Comment: Yeah the erorr message makes sense, but the goal here would be to read in part of the table using a query

Comment: @ben890 you could use a view for that purpose, or a copy of the subset of the table into another table, like `orders_1000` containing the result of selecting the first 1000.

Comment: is there no way to read in the result of query using this method?

Comment: @ben890 I'm not sure. Have you tried creating a view for this purpose?